# $\{\sup_n X_n \leq a\} = \cap_n \{X_n \leq a\}$

Tags: probability, self-learning

I would like to understand why this statement is true:

$\{\sup_n X_n \leq a\} = \cap_n \{X_n \leq a\}$

Could I have an example or a justification?
Here $X_n$ is a random variable.

This will also help me understand the set-theoretic definitions of limsup and liminf.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the following:

> Let $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions and let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega)\leq a$ if and only if $X_n(\omega)\leq a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Proof: If $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega)\leq a$ then clearly all $X_n(\omega)\leq a$. For the other direction assume by contradiction that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega)=b>a$ choose $\varepsilon<b-a$ then by the definition of supremum there exists $n$ such that $X_n(\omega)>b-\varepsilon>a$ which is absurd.

- Note that the statement in the question is not completely mathematical. A more accurate version would be 
  $$\{\omega \in \Omega : \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega)\leq a\} = \bigcap_n \{\omega \in \Omega : X_n(\omega)\leq a\}$$

Comment: I think your answer is very helpful! Can you clarify what is the set $\{X_n \leq a\}$.

Comment: @rannoudanames Thanks. I clarified this at the end, the set $\{X_n\leq a\}$ is a less formal way for $\{\omega \in \Omega : X_n(\omega)\leq a\}$.

Comment: Ohhhhh So $X(\omega)$ is a function that takes events in $\Omega$ into the reals. And in order for $X$ to be a random variable, it needs to be measurable. And for $A$ a subset of the reals, $X^{-1}(A)$ is an element of the $\sigma - algebra$ on $\Omega$ ?

Comment: @rannoudanames Exactly, but $\omega$ is not an event in $\Omega$ it is just an element. (An event is another way of saying "an element in the $\sigma$-algebra"). Also the property that $X^{-1}(A)$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra only needs to hold for a open sets of the reals. But overall you understand the picture.

Answer (score 2):

In short:$$\omega\in\{\sup_n X_n\leq a\}\iff\sup_nX_n(\omega)\leq a\iff\forall n\;X_n(\omega)\leq a\iff\omega\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n\leq a\}$$

hence:$$\{\sup_n X_n\leq a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n\leq a\}$$

Comment: Ok, so the infimum would equate to the union, correct?

Comment: What we do have is $\{\inf_nX_n\geq a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n\leq a\}$ and $\{\inf_nX_n<a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n<a\}$. Also $\{\sup_nX_n>a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n>a\}$.